# Merging Columns from Multiple Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am needing help merging some queries together that are based on COUNT() where Column A from each is the same and Columns B(+) are appended at the end, kind of like a summary. The problem, I bleieve, I am running into is that the 2nd and 3rd sets of query results don't all have responses. Below is an example to portray the best I can --

Separate Query Results:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | 1 |
| User 2 | 7 |
| User 3 | 2 |
| User 4 | 8 |

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 |  |  |  |
| User 2 |  | 7 |  |
| User 3 |  |  |  |
| User 4 |  |  |  |

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 |  |
| User 2 |  |
| User 3 |  |
| User 4 | 2 |

Combined Results Needed:

| Column A | Column B | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User 2 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| User 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User 4 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

So the best result I have retrieved is below:

| Column A | Column B | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 1 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 2 |
| User 2 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 2 |
| User 3 | 2 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 2 |
| User 4 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 2 |

I have pulled this result (and I apologize for how elementary/ridiculous this may be) using this query:

```sql
SELECT USER.text [User], Chapters [Column B], Titles [Column B], Epilogues [Column C], Prologues [Column D], Authors [Column B]

FROM BookUsers USER,

(SELECT UploadBy [User], COUNT(ChapName) [Chapters] FROM Chapters WHERE (UploadDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') AND UploadBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') GROUP BY UploadBy) AS Chapter, 

(SELECT CreatedBy [User], COUNT(Titles) [Titles], COUNT(Epilogues) [Epilogues], COUNT(Prologues) [Prologues] FROM Title_LOGS WHERE (CreatedDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') AND CreatedBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') GROUP BY CreatedBy
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ModifiedBy [User], COUNT(Titles) [Titles], COUNT(Epilogues) [Epilogues], COUNT(Prologues) [Prologues] FROM Title_LOGS WHERE (ModifiedDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') AND ModifiedBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') GROUP BY ModifiedBy) AS Title,

(SELECT CreatedBy [User], COUNT(Authors) [Authors] FROM Authors WHERE (CreatedDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') AND CreatedBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') GROUP BY CreatedBy) AS Author

WHERE USER.id IN (Chapter.[User])
GROUP BY USER.text, Chapters, Titles, Epilogues, Prologues, Authors
```

Again, the desrired result I am looking for is:

Combined Results Needed:

| Column A | Column B | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User 2 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| User 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| User 4 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as all of your result sets contain { User1, User2, User3 ...} you could join the resultsets on the [User] column, like this:

```
SELECT Users.text [User], Chapters [Column B], Titles [Column B], 
       Epilogues [Column C], Prologues [Column D], Authors [Column B]
FROM BookUsers Users
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT UploadBy [User], COUNT(ChapName) [Chapters] 
        FROM Chapters 
        WHERE (UploadDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') 
          AND UploadBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') 
        GROUP BY UploadBy
       ) AS Chapter ON Users.[User] = Chapter.[User]
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT CreatedBy [User], COUNT(Titles) [Titles], COUNT(Epilogues) [Epilogues], COUNT(Prologues) [Prologues] 
        FROM Title_LOGS 
        WHERE (CreatedDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') 
          AND CreatedBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') 
        GROUP BY CreatedBy
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ModifiedBy [User], COUNT(Titles) [Titles], COUNT(Epilogues) [Epilogues], COUNT(Prologues) [Prologues] 
        FROM Title_LOGS 
        WHERE (ModifiedDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') 
          AND ModifiedBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') 
        GROUP BY ModifiedBy
       ) AS Title ON Users.[User] = Title.[User]
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT CreatedBy [User], COUNT(Authors) [Authors] 
        FROM Authors 
        WHERE (CreatedDate between '01/01/2023' and '07/31/2023') 
          AND CreatedBy IN ('User 1','User 2','User 3','User 4') 
        GROUP BY CreatedBy
       ) AS Author ON Users.[User] = Author.[User]

 WHERE USER.id IN (Chapter.[User])
 GROUP BY Users.text, Chapters, Titles, Epilogues, Prologues, Authors
```

Generally, joining data on text columns is not ideal (because it is slow), but sometimes you have to use what you've got.

Comment: Thank you!! That gave me what I needed. I tried using some JOINS but just couldn't get them right for some reason but this approach gave me my solution..thanks again!

Comment: If this gave you the solution could you please mark this as the answer